# Textarea update not persisting to database through vuejs $emit event, axios and laravel backend api

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am very new to vuejs, working on implementing a to-do list that can be updated after task creation. I have a child component for each row in a table containing the textarea to be updated that emits an event to the parent to-do list component that calls an update method with axios. The field I am trying to update is 'description'.

Child component code:

```
<textarea v-model="task.description" @blur="$emit('update', task)" />

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    task: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
```

Parent component code:

```
<ChildComponent
    v-for="task in tasks"
    :key="task.id"
    :task="task"
    :project="project"
    @delete="deleteTask"
    @update="updateTask"
    />
.
.
.
methods: {
    async updateTask(taskData) {
       try {
        await this.$axios.patch(`projects/${taskData.project.id}/tasks/${taskData.id}`)
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
    }
```

Using vue devtools chrome extension, the event tab shows:

```
name:"update"
type:"$emit"
source:"<ChildComponent>"
payload:Array[1]
  0:Object
    created_at:"2020-07-07 14:01:46"
    created_by:1
    description:"Updated Task Description"
    id:43
    project:Object
    project_id:1
    updated_at:"2020-07-07 14:01:46"
```

However, the following is the JSON response from my api controller:

```
{"data":{
  "id":43,
  "created_by":1,
  "project_id":1,
  "description":"Original Description",
  "created_at":"2020-07-07 14:01:46",
  "updated_at":"2020-07-07 14:01:46"}
}
```

And the TasksController:

```
$task->update($request->all());
        return response()->json([
            'data' => $task,
        ], 202);
```

Currently, the textarea is not updating or persisting to the database. I don't know what I am missing. Any help is appreciated, I have tried implementing what I have found online without success.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not PATCHing your data through to the server.  Try the following:

```
    async updateTask(taskData) {
       try {
        await this.$axios.patch(`projects/${taskData.project.id}/tasks/${taskData.id}`, taskData)
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
    }
```

The second parameter to `$axios.patch` should be the data you'd like to send to the server.